# foreach doesn't work, but mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a beginner and have a catalog of films and music on a local website, just a hobby, and I use CodeIgniter. Everything was fine and decided to upgrade to version 3.0 of CodeIgniter. All pages are loading without problems, but the album page:

```
$string = $this->uri->segment(3);
$array=explode("8803",$string);
$id = ($array[1] / 11 );
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get('albuns');  
foreach ($query->result() as $data);
$id = $data->id;
$sqlDisc = "SELECT disc FROM songs
WHERE album_id = ".$id."
ORDER BY disc DESC";
$queryDisc = mysql_query($sqlDisc); //error msg listed below

$recDisc = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryDisc);
$numDisc = $recDisc['disc'];    
$disc_atual = 0
```

I'm getting this error: "mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead"

I had tried to use the foreach [model page] even in the previous version of the CI, but not working. I have no idea of the difference between 'mysql_fetch_assoc' and 'foreach':

```
function get_disc()
{
$string = $this->uri->segment(3);
$array=explode("8803",$string);
$id = ($array[1] / 11 );
$this->db->select('disc');
$this->db->where('album_id', $id);
$this->db->order_by('disc', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get('songs');
return $query->result();
}
```

Why "$array=explode("8803",$string);"?
localhost/wd/music/album/the-beatles-white-album-remastered-dts-51-wd88033443

When was working:
"Lista das Trilhas - Disco 1" in English means "Track Listing - Disc 1"

Using foreach the disc number is not shown:
"Lista das Trilhas"

I appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all use SQLI or PDO. To use this please go to database.php and change driver to mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

i mean the obvious thing is to change your code a bit - i'll try to help so you can stand on your own feets

```
$string = $this->uri->segment(3);
$array=explode("8803",$string);
$id = ($array[1] / 11 );
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get('albuns');  
foreach ($query->result() as $data)
{
    $id = $data->id;
    $queryDisc = $this->db
        ->select("disc")
        ->from("songs")
        ->where("album_id",$id)
        ->order_by("disc","DESC")
        ->get();

    $numDisc = $queryDisc->num_rows();
    if ($numDisc > 0)
    {
        foreach($queryDisc->result() AS $objDisc)
        {
            print_r($objDisc);
        }
    }
    $disc_atual = 0
}
```

Comment: Hi Vinie, thank you. 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli' is already encoded in database.php, came as the CI site, I just put the name of the database, user and password and nothing else.

Comment: Hi Vinie, thank you. 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli' is already encoded in database.php, came as the CI site, I just put the name of the database, user and password and nothing else. I will change the page and very soon give you feedback. Thanks again.